# Using same packages in multiple npm projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, npm

I have a project which has a single server in node.js and multiple javascript clients (written in vue)

Currently, each client project has different babel versions, eslint versions and even different versions of component libraries which causes inconsistency issues across my client applications.

What is the best practice for fixing this?

Is some kind of package.json inheritance the way to go?

Comment: There is a way to do so, you may create a new repository and add all common packages inside. Then in each client repository you could use git submodule to inherit all common packages

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may include a vue header where all the links to your component libraries are defined. So you got one file where you link all your components and versions, and many files where this file gets included. So when you update one clients component, the component will change for all the other clients too.

Comment: That's a good idea, what can I do about the common build tools like babel?